# Symfony2 and Submit wit JavaScript: How to get html content

Tags: php, javascript, json, post, symfony

I have a form in Symfony2 project and I need to submit form. The first idea was to submit using ajax but the problem is that this will not pass the symfony2 required validation and I am getting the CSRF error message (see my precedant question : [Symfony2: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154035/symfony2-the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form)).

Thank's to @Elnur's answer, I am able now to submit the form using $post but have another problem.

With Ajay, I am getting back an html response and I was able to asign this response to an HTML element:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: href,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap").html( data.content );
    }
});
```

Here is the response I am getting from:

```
<div class="item item-last">
<h1>Create Affiliation</h1>
        <div class="error">
        <ul><li>The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form</li></ul>
        <ul><li>The Affiliation should not be blank</li></ul>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="item item-last">
<form action="/app_dev.php/user/submission/affiliation/create/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32?ajax=no" method="POST" class="authorForm" >
    <div style="float:left;">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="submissionAffiliationForm_affiliation" class=" required">Affiliation</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="submissionAffiliationForm_affiliation" name="submissionAffiliationForm[affiliation]" required="required"    size="40" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="button button-left button-cancel">
                        <img src="/bundles/sciforumversion2/images/design/new/button-red.png"/>
                        <a href="/app_dev.php/user/submission/author/edit/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32/0" class="submission_link">cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="button button-left button-cancel">
                        <img src="/bundles/sciforumversion2/images/design/new/button.png"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="login" value="submit" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="submissionAffiliationForm__token" name="submissionAffiliationForm[_token]" value="de9690f61f0ee5f30fdcc5152f44e76787f34bbb" />

</form>
</div>
```

But now, when using post:

```
$.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function (data) {
    $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap").html( data );
});
```

I am not getting anymore HTML but a JSON formated response and I don't know how to extract he right information from.

Here is the response I am getting from the post:

```
{"responseCode":400,"errors":false,"submitted":false,"content":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text\/html; charset=utf-8\" \/>\n        <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=\/app_dev.php\/user\/submission\/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32\" \/>\n\n        <title>Redirecting to \/app_dev.php\/user\/submission\/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32<\/title>\n    <\/head>\n    <body>\n        Redirecting to <a href=\"\/app_dev.php\/user\/submission\/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32\">\/app_dev.php\/user\/submission\/4a0ad9f8020c5cd5712ff4c4c8921b32<\/a>.\n    <\/body>\n<\/html>","notice":""}
```

Here is how it looks like th controller:

```
$em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    // get the user object
    $user       = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $submission = $em->getRepository('SciForumVersion2Bundle:Submission')->findOneBy( array("hash_key"=>$hash_key) );
    $author     = $em->getRepository('SciForumVersion2Bundle:SubmissionAuthor')->findOneBy( array("id"=>$author_id, "hash_key"=>$hash_key) );
    if( $author == null ) {
        $author = new SubmissionAuthor();
        $author->setPerson( new Person() );
    }

    $enquiry    = new Affiliation();
    $formType   = new SubmissionAffiliationFormType();
    $form       = $this->createForm($formType, $enquiry);

    $request    = $this->getRequest();
    $valid      = true;
    $error      = '';
    if( $request->get('cancel') == 'yes' ) return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SciForumVersion2Bundle_user_submission', array("key"=>$submission->getHashKey())));
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST' && $request->get('ajax') == 'no') {

        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($valid = $form->isValid()) {

            if( $valid ) {

                $em->persist($enquiry);
                $em->flush();

                $uAff = new UserAffiliation();
                $uAff->setUserId( $user->getId() );
                $uAff->setAffiliationId( $enquiry->getId() );
                $uAff->setUser( $user );
                $uAff->setAffiliation( $enquiry );
                $em->persist($uAff);
                $em->flush();

                // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
                // the form if they refresh the page
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SciForumVersion2Bundle_user_submission', array("key"=>$submission->getHashKey())));
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show us your Controller?

Comment: @Touki, thank you. I will update my question in a minute.

Comment: Your AJAX request expects a return. Symfony is trying to redirect the user. You cannot redirect from an AJAX request. If you want to show the content just do. `$("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap").html( data.content );`

Comment: @Touki, where should I do this, in my post function, instead of     .html( data ); I have to put     .html( data.content ); ?

Comment: Yes. This will fill your ".itemwrap" with Symfony redirecting.

Comment: I allready try that but the data.content is undefined and I am not redirected at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18953/discussion-between-touki-and-milos)

Comment: Are you there @Touki, can we continue in chat please?

Comment: Dear @Touki, could you please add a short answer to the question, so I can accept it and close de question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're returning a full new HTML content.
You need to return only informations that your JS can understand and treat the way you want.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

This class in SF allows you to return plain content.

Here's a way to use it.

```
if ($valid) {
    $data = array(
        'success' => true,
        'responseCode' => 307, /* Redirect Temp */
        'redirectURI' => $this->generateUrl('SciForumVersion2Bundle_user_submission', array("key"=>$submission->getHashKey())),
        'message' => '<h3>You\'re about to be redirected...</h3>'
    );
} else {
    $data = array(
        'success' => false,
        'responseCode' => 400, /* Bad Request */
        'message' => '<h3 class="error">Cannot send form<br>* Field NAME is empty</h3>'
    );
}
$json = json_encode($data);
/* Response($data,$statusCode,$additionnalHeaders) */
return new Response($json,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
```

Then in your JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "uri/to/controller",
    type: "POST",
    data: values, /* Sent data */
    cache: false,
    success : function(data,e,xhr){
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            if (data.responseCode == 200) { /* Success, just a message */
                $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html(data.message);
            } else if (data.responseCode == 307) { /* Redirection */
                $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html(data.message);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(window).attr("location",data.redirectURI);
                },3000);
            } else if (data.responseCode == 400) { /* Invalid Form */
                $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html(data.message);
            } else { /* Could not understand Response Code */
                $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap")
                    .html("<h3>Technical issue occured. Please come back later.</h3>");
            }
        } else {
            $("#content .contentwrap .itemwrap")
                .html("<h3>Technical issue occured. Please come back later.</h3>");
        }
    }
})
```

You could imagine any parameter to pass through `$data`

I used `HTTP/1.1` codes to *talk* with Javascript but you can use anything you want
Ex:

```
'action' => 'redirect'
'youAreGoingTo' => 'printAwesomeMessage'
```

JS

```
if (data.action == 'redirect')

if (data.youAreGoingTo == 'printAwesomeMessage')
```

Comment: Great answer and excellent help, a real profesionnal. Thank you so much.